# Unable to Start `mongodb` Server. illegal instruction: Core Dumped

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying to install `mongodb` on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I followed al the instructions on the Mongodb official website, but I have been receiving the same error on running `mongod` or `mongo`.

The error message is `illegal instruction:  core Dumped`the instruction on https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I followed

Comment: If you use `jammy` rather than `focal`, does it work then?

Comment: I was using Focal on my Desktop (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), and ```mongodb``` is working fine. I bought a new laptop PC last month and I tried Jammy (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), but on installing ```mongodb```, I receive an error.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit ... or maybe you got my meaning anyway. If during your local list file creation, you use `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list`, does that work?